# "First time in" or "first time to"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, idioms, ellipsis

In the following sentence:

> 1. "Is this your first _______________ to Sydney?"

I thought that the possible answers were "visit", "trip" or "journey".(any others?)  However, I've just seen on the internet the sentence:

> 2. "Is this your first time to Sydney?"

I tend to think that this is not correct and would rather say:

> 3. "Is this your first time in Sydney?"

Is sentence 2 correct?

Answer (score 3):

> Is this your first **trip** to Sydney?
>   Is this your first **visit** to Sydney?
>   Is this your first **stay** in Sydney?
>   How is your first **experience** of Sydney?
>   What is your first **impression(s)** of Sydney?

All generally mean

> Is this your first **time** in Sydney?

Either of your questions may be asked

> Is this your first time to *(come to)* Sydney?
>   Is this your first time *(to be)* in Sydney?

if you're wondering if the listener has ever been to Sydney before.

Comment: Good answer. As Peter pointed it out, *to* is a motion preposition and can be used as in the above sentences.

Comment: It is a good answer. If I had to extract the key question from the ... question, I'd pick *Is 2 correct.* This answer ... answers that, but I think a direct statement that it's correct, at the top, would improve it.

Answer (score 0):

"Is this your first time to Sydney?" sounds flatly wrong to me, a 64-year-old native speaker of American English. I suppose it could be acceptable in some other variants of English, since it is a matter of usage rather than grammar, but I just don't know. Your other examples sound fine.

Comment: It's certainly interesting that it sounds wrong to you. But it's a familiar structure to me in Standard American English.